# Função para criar botões de acordo com o banco de dados

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, dart, button

Tenho em meu banco de dados diversas informações e que para cada informação deve existir um botão que direcione o usuário para a tela onde será exibido um guia de acordo com a opção escolhida. Entretanto, o número de dados no banco deve alterar de acordo com o usuário, ou seja, preciso de uma função que faça a leitura do banco, identifique quantos botões devem ser criados e ai então criar os botões...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'Embarque.dart';
import 'Settings.dart';
import 'package:cargas_app/database/sqlite/connection.dart';

class menu extends StatefulWidget {
  const menu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _menuState createState() => _menuState();
}

class _menuState extends State<menu> {
  String num_embarque = "";
  var total_embarques = 0;
  var j = 0;
  String? nm_emb = "";



//Função que faz a leitura no banco, retorna o numero dos embarques e a quantidade

  ler_embarque() async {
    final Database db = await Connection.get;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> url =
        await db.rawQuery('SELECT nr_embarque FROM embarque');
    var embarques = url.forEach((row) => print(row));

    List<Map<String, dynamic>> conta_embarques =
        await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(nr_embarque) FROM embarque');
    String cont_embarques = conta_embarques.toString();
    var cont = RegExp(r'(?<= )(.*)(?=})');
    var match0 = cont.firstMatch(cont_embarques);
    var total_embarques_string = match0?.group(0);
    total_embarques = int.parse('$total_embarques_string');
    print("Embarques: $total_embarques"); //mostra o total de embarques

    while (j < total_embarques) {
      List nr_embarque = url;
      num_embarque = nr_embarque[j].toString();

      var re = RegExp(r'(?<= )(.*)(?=})');
      var match1 = re.firstMatch(num_embarque);
      nm_emb = match1?.group(0);

      print(j);
      print(nm_emb);

      j++;
      return add_buttom();
    }
  }


//Função que adiciona o botão, ao meu entendimento se fez necessário chamar a função do banco dentro da função do botão, por conta de não poder ser uma função async

  add_buttom() {
    if (j == 0) {
      ler_embarque();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(
            "Embarque: $nm_emb",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
          ),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Color(0xffbDCDCDC),
            onPrimary: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Embarque(),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      });

      if (j > total_embarques) {
        return add_buttom();
      } else {
        return ler_embarque();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    new Container();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text("Embarques"),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffb0000CD),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[400]),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 1000, height: 50),
              child: add_buttom(),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 32,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Settings(),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.settings),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffb0000CD),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

...ao chegar no child, dentro da ConstrainedBox, eu mando executar a função "add_button()", que manda executar a leitura no banco de dados(ler_embarque()), retorna os valores necessários e chama um ElevatedButton. Até a parte da leitura no banco ele funciona certinho e exibe as informações pedidas no console, mas na hora de criar o ElevatedButton recebo:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building menu(dirty, state: _menuState#7a0ff):
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

The relevant error-causing widget was
menu
lib\pages\Login.dart:39
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

Comment: ainda sem respostas...

Answer (score 1):

Olá

Tua função add_button não está retornando nenhum elemento (Widget), entretanto ela está sendo utilizada como se fosse resultar um widget

```
add_buttom() {
if (j == 0) {
  ler_embarque();
} else {
  setState(() {
    ElevatedButton(  ///<---------- aqui deveria ser um return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text(
        "Embarque: $nm_emb",
```

Neste caso, segundo seu body: o mesmo está esperando por um Widget vindo da função add_buttom

```
 body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[400]),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 1000, height: 50),
          child: add_buttom(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 32,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Além disso seu código pode melhorar em termos de separação das funções, pois não está claro o objetivo e nem se as funções vão resultar no que você está esperando.

Um bom caminho é separar as funções que retornam Widgets, das que servem apenas para garantir a lógica de dados. Por exemplo, a função ler_embarque não deveria estar inserida na função add_buttom(), pois, primeiro acho que você deve montar sua lista e depois chamar a função que desenhará a lista na tela.

Como você está usando o StatefullWidget experimente colocar as chamadas de funções que vão montar as tabelas no initState do teu formulário.

No teu build também não é necessário este Container no inicio:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    new Container();   /// <--- sem finalidade
    return Scaffold(
```

Enfim, quando se está aprendendo acontece isso mesmo. Mas, a minha dica final é: - Faça uma lista com os botões, melhore a rotina de le_embarque para adicionar elementos na lista e depois implemente dentro do build a rotina que desenhe os botões na tela.

Se der, publica no github, pois pode facilitar para o pessoal te ajudar.
Sucesso ai.